# Why can we explicitly unwrap this optional without worrying about a crash?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, option-type

I was watching [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NptQoqV2agI) video and at the 2 minute mark he explains somehting that I really don't understand.

Code:

```
class Order {
    var product: Product?
}

class Product {
    var order: Order?
}

var myOrder = Order()
var iPhone6 = Product()

myOrder.product = iPhone6
myOrder.product!.order = myOrder
```

He says, when talking about the explicit unwrapping, that if the property is null, the statement won't crash and get a null reference. He says the statement will have no effect if the product happens to be nil upon explicit unwrapping. I thought this was the case with using the question mark, like `myOrder.product?.order`, but NOT with the exclamation point.

Comment: If you don't assign a (non-nil) value to `myOrder.product` then `myOrder.product!.order = myOrder` crashes. You can easily verify that yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Straight to your question - here you are sure about creating your `Order` instance so you don't have to check for `nil`. But in other cases you will have to check for `nil`.

What bothers me here is that you will have a *retain cycle*. So what you can make to avoid retain cycles is to keep weak reference to the `Order` instance inside your `Product` class (an order should always have a product but a product can go without an order). Something like this:

```
class Product {
    weak var order: Order?
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what the guy in the video did, creating a retain cycle and resolving it doing that exact change. Thanks! The only thing that still I don't get about what he said was, "the statement will have no effect if the product happens to be nil upon explicit unwrapping." It will never be nil first of all, and second of all, if it was, it would crash. So what does he mean by this then?

Comment: I believe he means scenarios when you don't exactly know if an optional is nil or not and not particularly this one.

Comment: Right, but in that scenario, you would use `?` instead of `!` correct?

Comment: If you use `?` then you will have the so called `optional chaining` and yes, you can go with it. If `product` is nil you will fail to set the `order` without having a runtime crash.